# Syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have code auto-formatting and do we need to tweak what we had on the StackExchange tag?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-we-have-code-auto-formatting-and-do-we-need-to-tweak-what-we-had-on-the-stac)

Readability isn't exactly the strong suit of Mathematica anyway, and the absence of syntax highlighting in code blocks makes this even worse. Could we have something enabled like there already is for stackoverflow, so that code is automatically prettyprinted ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753508/custom-colorfunction-colordata-in-arrayplot-and-similar-functions))?

Comment: It has been turned on, but they don't do customizations, and at the moment, you'll have to use a language tag explicitly. The default isn't very pretty either, and the best bet is to develop a custom .js file. [Support has been requested from the SO javascript community](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8957682/), so we should wait and watch. In the mean time, I think this should be closed as a dupe of the other